# Python: random date generation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate random dates in the same format as the input, but no matter how many times I run the code, I want it to return the same random date, against each input value.

I'm reading from csv file to a data frame as follows:

`in_df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',sep="\t", encoding='ISO-8859-1',usecols=['MY_DATE'])`

Input dataframe:

```
MY_DATE 
0   2015-11-30 
1   2016-10-14 
2   2015-11-20
```

Expected output after 1st call to function:

```
MY_DATE 
0   2018-10-22 
1   2019-06-15 
2   2007-09-01
```

Expected output after 2nd call to function, for the same input:

```
MY_DATE 
0   2018-10-22 
1   2019-06-15 
2   2007-09-01
```

`2015-11-30` results in, say, `2018-10-22` on first run, but doesn't result in the same date when I rerun it, even after setting the prop as global.

Here's my code snippet:

```
global prop
prop= random.random()
def gen_exp_dt(prop,start_dttm, end_dttm, format=None):
   stime = time.mktime(time.strptime(start_dttm,format))
   etime = time.mktime(time.strptime(end_dttm, format))
   rtime = stime + (prop * (etime - stime))
   return  time.strftime(format, time.localtime(rtime))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What dates and how?

Comment: question seems ambiguous and unclear, specify your input and your desire output and what you are getting on your own attempt to solve problem.

Comment: @coldspeed for `2015-11-30` I want to generate some random date (ex: `2018-10-22`), but every call to the function must return the same date (`2018-10-22`) when input is `2015-11-30`

Comment: As you are using `random` then just `random.seed()` it with the same value and you will get the same results.

Comment: @AChampion I don't think that's what they're looking for. They want the same random date for a given input (depending on the input). @OP, what is `prop`? This is a little too much. Can't you be satisfied with random dates within a given range? Because _that_ is easy.

Comment: @coldspeed prop is a masking factor. Makes it difficult to trace back to the input date, by applying any simple formula on the output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use each date as your random seed.  That way, each time you apply the function, you will get the same result for each date.

Next, generate a random integer between whatever range you want (I chose 1 and `time.time()`), and convert to a string with your desired format:

```
def random_date(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    d = random.randint(1, int(time.time()))
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This will produce consistent results:

```
df
      MY_DATE
0  2015-11-30
1  2016-10-14
2  2015-11-20

df.MY_DATE.apply(random_date)

0    1978-07-06
1    1971-03-30
2    1998-06-05
Name: MY_DATE, dtype: object

df.MY_DATE.apply(random_date)

0    1978-07-06
1    1971-03-30
2    1998-06-05
Name: MY_DATE, dtype: object
```

Comment: I used `datetime.date.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` to make this work.